# Scheme best practise bracket scheme

Tags: scheme

Are there any good solution with brackets and line breaks to make a scheme expression like this clearly arranged?

```
(* (cond ((> a b) a)
((< a b) b)
(else -1))
(+ a 1))
```

Comment: whitespace is used to align arguments in a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [coding style guidelines](http://community.schemewiki.org/cgi-bin/scheme.cgi?scheme-style) you can follow that makes your code readable by you and other programmers. How your code was presented it is utterly unreadable.

I agree with @uselpa that the formattign in his answer is OK and it even is ok by the guidelines. I might have done something like this:

```
;;; Returns the Parker square of
;;; two nebulous numbers
(define (fun-name a b)
  (define biggest
    (cond
      ((> a b) a)
      ((< a b) b)
      (else -1)))

  (* biggest (+ a 1)))
```

This shows two things. A comment might help explaining what the procedure does and local bindings might shed some light on what's happening in the first step and reduces the complexity and ease readability. No matter what language you are writing in these are good things.

Comment: Good coding-style link!

Answer (score 2):

I would go for something like this:

```
(* (cond
     ((> a b) a)
     ((< a b) b)
     (else -1))
   (+ a 1))
```

I don't use brackets in addition to parentheses, and the point here is to align the arguments of `cond` and `*`.

Comment: That, and every scheme implementation I am aware of has a pretty-printer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using scheme since 40 years, not in job but for studying the SICP.

In the first time I put every parentheses pair with it own indentation and every closing parenthese on its own line.

```
(* 
    (cond
       (  (> a b) 
           a
       )
       ( (< a b) 
         b
       )
       (   else 
          -1
       )
   ) ;; cond
   (+ a 1)
) ;; product
```

Maybe the code is not easier to read than a more compact code, but while writing it was more clear to me.
Several years later, after learning python I changed my style total.
(In python the indentation is a syntatic element. You have no {} like in C and Java.) I used only the indentation to structure my code and put the closing parentheses in the same row. My code looks as in the earlier answers.

Important is to use an editor, which shows matching parentheses.

In short: Be careful to structure your code by graphic elements. There are several possibilities to do it.

Comment: You're solution is pretty readable. but I think there are lots of almost empty rows. I do prefer the other solution but it's a nice variation

Answer (score -1):

For the record, this is what [raco fmt](https://docs.racket-lang.org/fmt/index.html) does with it, i.e. pretty much the same as @uselpa, except for the square brackets. That of course requires an interpreter that would accept square brackets (interpreted in the same way as the regular brackets, recommended for `cond`, for better readability).

```
(* (cond
     [(> a b) a]
     [(< a b) b]
     [else -1])
   (+ a 1))
```

Comment: @anonymous, care to at least explain the minus one? `raco fmt` being the official formatting solution from a community that can be considered as highly skilled in Scheme, since it provides extensive support for most (if not all) of the existing dialects of Scheme, I'd be curious to hear how this answer does not qualify as "useful". I'd argue its origin (and I'm talking about the tool, not about myself), makes it an expert answer.